# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [.../helloworld.xhtml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi everyone i know that there were dozens of similar questions, but I couldn't find a solution that works for me. I want to make simple 'hello world' app using spring mvc. It gives me 404 error,
and on console:

```
avr. 22, 2015 4:10:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/WEB-  INF/views/helloworld.xhtml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<bean           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.xhtml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SpringController {

String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
}

}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<h3>
    <a href="hello?name=youness">Click Here</a>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**WEB-INF/views/helloworld.xhtml**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 4 MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h2>
        ${message} ${name}
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and when i click on the link "click here"

im getting this error:

```
  avr. 23, 2015 2:48:58 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound     noHandlerFound
    AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/WEB-  INF/views/helloworld.xhtml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the `servlet-mapping` entry in web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestion but didn t work for me . the console:
    avr. 27, 2015 11:59:44 AM    org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI   [/SpringMVC] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be your java class file is not there in your target war.
To make sure first do maven clean compile package and then publish your war to server,make sure you don't get any error while publishing war file.
I was also facing the same issue and resolved it by doing above steps.